# How do I supress sqldf messages in R Markdown?

Tags: html, r, markdown, knitr, sqldf

I have an R code chunk that calls the `sqldf` package. When I knit the Rmd into HTML, the HTML prints and displays the sqldf code. How do I hide/supress it? I've already tried to tinker with the chunk settings by turning `ECHO` off, suppressing warnings, etc...

This is the printed text I want to remove from the HTML:

> '## sqldf: library(RSQLite)
>   '## sqldf: m <- dbDriver("SQLite")
>   '## sqldf: connection <- dbConnect(m, dbname = ":memory:")
>   '## sqldf: initExtension(connection)
>   '## sqldf: dbWriteTable

....etc.

These are the current settings of my chunk:

````
```{r sqldata, echo = FALSE, message=F, warning=F}

library(sqldf)
MyQuery <- sqldf(MyString,verbose=TRUE) 

```
````

Comment: Output you have asked for (`verbose=TRUE`) is not messages.  Note that `options(sqldf.verbose = TRUE); sqldf(MyString)` would also output the RSQLite code.  You could put the `options` statement in a separate chunk and display that chunk without evaluating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want any output at all (no messages, no data frame, no code shown...), set `include = FALSE` as a chunk option.

If you want to show the code, but you don't like the sqldf notes, change `verbose = TRUE` to `verbose = FALSE`.

If you look at the `sqldf` code, you see things like this:

```
if (verbose) {
    cat("sqldf: dbGetQuery(connection, '", x[i], 
        "')\n", sep = "")
}
```

So those outputs are produced by `cat()`, not `message()` or `warning()`, so to knitr they are indistinguishable from the object printed to the console at the end.

If you really want to show the code (chunk option `echo = TRUE`) with (sqldf option) `verbose = TRUE`, but you don't want all the verbose output (seems strange) I'd suggest spoofing it with two code chunks, one that is not evaluated but displayed, and one that is evaluated but not included.

````
```{r sqldata, eval = FALSE}
library(sqldf)
MyQuery <- sqldf(MyString,verbose=TRUE)
```


```{r sqldata, eval = TRUE, include = FALSE}
library(sqldf)
MyQuery <- sqldf(MyString)
```
````